# Probability distribution function expressed in terms of a divergent series

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, integral, taylor-series

I'm interested in finding the CDF and PDF of $U_i$ defined as follows, 
$$U_i=\frac g{d^{\alpha}}$$
where $g$ is a gamma distributed random variable with shape $k$ and scale $\theta$, and $d$ is a random variable with distribution $f_d(x)=\frac {2x}{R^2}, 0\le x \le R$.
To find the CDF of  $U_i$ 
$$F_{U_i}(y)=P(U_i<y)=\int_0^R F_g(yx^\alpha)f_d(x)dx$$ 
where $F_g(y)$ is the CDF of gamma distributed random variable. 

 After performing the integration, which requires the use of the expansion of incomplete gamma function, I came to the following CDF: 
$$F_{U_i}(y)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {2(-1)^nR^{k\alpha+n\alpha}y^{k+n}}{\Gamma(k)n!\theta^{k+n}(k+n)(k\alpha+n\alpha+2)}$$
I want the CDF in this format because my ultimate goal is to find the CDF of $U=\sum_{i=1}^NU_i$ which requires me to find the Laplace transform of $F_{U_i}(y)$ and raise it to power $N$. 

Now it's easy to find the PDF of $U_i$, i.e. $f_{U_i}(y)=\frac {d}{dy}F_{U_i}(y)$. 

I'm looking for someone to clarify these points to me:

My derived $f_{U_i}(y)$ doesn't make sense to me, because it's based on a divergent series. How can it's integration from zero to infinity equals one?

In Matlab I took the $K^{th}$ elements of the series, and plotted it along with the histogram of 1000 $U_i$'s, the two plots are not related.

If you look at the definition of $U_i$, $U_i$ can take values from 0 to infinity, high values take less probability. This fact is not clear in the derived distribution $f_{U_i}(y)$. What is the domain of the derived PDF? What is the integration limit if I wannna find $F_\epsilon(\epsilon)=\int f(y)F_{U_i}(\epsilon(y+\sigma^2))dy$? where $f(y)$ is another density function.

How can I simulate the derived PDF in Matlab to check if it's really correlated with $U_i$

Comment: Please explain why you think this series diverges.  As far as I can tell, for most values of $\alpha$ (including all positive values) it is an *entire* function: it converges everywhere in the complex plane.

Comment: @whuber if it converges how do you proof $\int_0^\infty f_{U_i}(y) dy=1$?

Comment: That's irrelevant, because a more basic problem is that $F_{U_i}$ obviously is not a CDF, since it is directly proportional to $\theta^{-k}.$ Thus, there is *at most* one $\theta$ that could possibly make this a valid CDF and for arbitrary $\theta$ and $k$ it cannot be a CDF.

Comment: If it's not a CDF then was my derivation wrong?

Comment: It must have been. There are some simple checks.  One of them is that because $\theta$ is a scale parameter for $g,$ it must be a scale parameter for $U_i,$ whence the CDF must be a function of $y/\theta$--but it is not. Another is to plug in simple values of parameters. E.g., $\alpha=1,$ $k=1,$ $R=1$ gives a sum that evaluates to $(y^2 + 2e^{-y}(y+1)-2)/y^2,$ which works, so you might be close.

Comment: @whuber are you saying that when $\alpha =1, k=1, R=1$ the series converges to $(y^2+2e^{-y}(y+1)-2)/y^2$? If yes, how did you get that?

Comment: @whuber I've corrected it, I've added $\theta^n$ in the denominator. Any way, still wondering if any answer to my previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103470/discussion-between-aymen-kareem-and-whuber).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**The series converges to a distribution function.  It can be evaluated in closed form.**

Upon identifying the terms varying with $n,$ write your function in a simpler form as

$$\begin{equation*}
F_{U_i}(y)=\frac{2(R^{\alpha}y/\theta)^k}{\Gamma(k)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {(-R^\alpha y / \theta)^n}{n!(k+n)((k+n)\alpha+2)} \\
= \frac{2x^k}{\Gamma(k)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!\,(k+n)((k+n)\alpha+2)}
\end{equation*}$$

for $x = R^\alpha y /\theta.$  In other words, **$\sigma=\theta/R^\alpha$ is a scale parameter.**

Assuming (from the form of the expression $g/d^\alpha$) that $\alpha \gt 0,$ every one of the terms in the sum is bounded above in size by $x^n / n!$ showing the sum is dominated by the *absolutely convergent* series for $\exp(x),$ whence **the sum converges absolutely for all $x.$**

To evaluate such a sum we will use partial fractions.  Consider the simpler function

$$h(x, a) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^n}{n! (a+n)}$$

with $a \ge 0.$  Similar considerations demonstrate absolute convergence so we may differentiate term by term to obtain

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} \left(x^a h(x,a)\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n+a-1}}{n!} =  x^{a-1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{n}}{n!} = x^{a-1} e^{-x}.$$

Therefore

$$h(x,a) = x^{-a} \int^x t^{a-1} e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t = C + x^{-a}\,\gamma(a, x),$$

where $\gamma$ is the [lower Incomplete Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function) and $C$ is a constant of integration.   It can be found by applying L'Hopital's Rule to $x^{-a}\int_0^x t^{a-1} e^{-t}\mathrm{d}t$ as $x\to 0^+$ and comparing the resulting limit of $C+1/a$ to $h(0,a) = (-0)^0/(0!(a+0)) = 1/a$ to conclude $C=0.$

Now because

$$\frac{1}{(k+n)((k+n)\alpha+2)} = \frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{1}{(k+n)(k+n+2/\alpha)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{k+n} - \frac{1}{k+n+2/\alpha}\right),$$

we again exploit the absolute convergence of the series for $F_{U_i}$ and set $a=k,$ $b=k+2/\alpha$ to express it as

> $$F_{U_i}(y) = \frac{2x^k}{\Gamma(k)}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-x)^n}{n!\,(k+n)((k+n)\alpha+2)} = \frac{\gamma(k,x) - x^{-\frac{2}{\alpha}}\gamma(k+\frac{2}{\alpha},x)}{\Gamma(k)}$$ where $$x = y/\sigma = R^\alpha y / \theta \text{ and }\sigma=\theta/R^\alpha.$$

Differentiating this to obtain the density is straightforward, yielding

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} F^\prime_{U_i}(y) = \frac{2\gamma(k+2/\alpha, x)}{\alpha \Gamma(k) x^{1 + 2/\alpha}} \ge 0$$

and it is also elementary to establish that

$$\lim_{y\to\infty} F_{U_i}(y) = 1 \text{ and } \lim_{y\to 0^+} F_{U_i}(y) = 0.$$

Therefore $F_{U_i}$ is the CDF of a continuous random variable.

---

Almost any statistical computing platform will compute the CDF of Gamma variables (or, equivalently, of Chi-squared variables).  This is the normalized version of $\gamma.$  For instance, here are `R` implementations of $F_{U_i}$ and its derivative:

```R
# CDF
pFU <- function(x, k, alpha, scale=1) {
  x <- x / scale
  h <- function(x, a) 
    ifelse(x > 0, exp(pgamma(x, a, log.p=TRUE) + lgamma(a)), 1/a)
  (h(x, k) - x^(-2/alpha) * h(x, k + 2/alpha)) / gamma(k)
}

# PDF
dFU <- function(x, k, alpha, scale=1) {
  x <- x / scale
  ifelse(x <= 0, 0, 
         2/alpha * exp(-(1 + 2/alpha)*log(x) + pgamma(x, k+2/alpha, log.p=TRUE) + 
                         lgamma(k+2/alpha) - lgamma(k))) / scale
}
```

Here are plots of them using the `curve` function:

[image: Figure showing graphs of the CDF and PDF]

The underlying red curves use these functions.  As a check, overplotted in black are direct implementations of the original series (for the CDF) and a numerical derivative of `pFU` (for the PDF).

Comment: Great!!! Thank you very much.

Comment: How do you integrate the derived pdf from 0 to infinity and you get 1? How can I calculate the expected value?

Comment: (1) $F_{U_i}$ already is the integral of the PDF, so just take its limit as the argument goes to $\infty.$  (2) Compute the expected value by integrating $1-F_{U_i}(x)$ from $0$ to $\infty.$ Because $F_{U_i}$ has been expressed in terms of $\gamma,$ this looks is fairly simple.  I would integrate by parts.

Comment: please have a look at my new question. I need $E[x^2] $also